# Adobe SiteCatalyst:How to export the groups with list of usernames and report suite

Tags: adobe-analytics

i am working on Adobe SiteCatalyst.

i am able to download the groups with column names Group Name,Description,Users and Report Suites.

In above list am getting count of users and report suites.but i need a exact name instead of count how this can be done using Adobe Site Catalyst..

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built in report that will get you this. If there is a small number of users and you don't need to do it very often then you can do this manually. But it would be a pain.

If you think it is worth investing some time into this because you have a lot of users and/or you need to do this report often then you can use the Enterprise API to automate this report.

You will need to create a user with the Web Services permission. Then using that username and secret (be careful to use the exact format from the Admin tools->Company Settings->Web Services as there is a "loginCompany:username" format and special Shared Secret)

Then you can use the APIs assuming you have some development experience. This is a good starting point. https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/get-started/api-explorer#Permissions.GetGroup  and also look at GetGroups.

Best of luck C.